# Serialize an object differently depending on the user's privileges

Tags: php, serialization

Currently, in order to send the data from my web-app to the front-end, my classes implement the [`JsonSerializable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface.

But now, I would like to send to the front-end more information when the user has sufficient privileges. These privileges can only be known via an object of the class `Entity\User`, let's say `$user->hasPrivileges(…)` for instance.

Sadly, I can't provide the `$user` variable to the [`jsonSerialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) method. What is the cleanest way to achieve this objective?

Comment: And an happy new year to you all, of course :) !

Comment: So you have no clue which user is "logged in"?

Comment: @MatthiasDunkel I have: the user is represented by the `$user` variable. But I have no access to it in `jsonSerialize()`.

Comment: Can't you have a variable in the class which implements JsonSerializable which holds the user? Then you could access it like `$this->user`

Comment: @MatthiasDunkel Well, that's the proposition of dev-null-dweller and kuroi neko :) . See below for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you could add an attribute to your front-end class to filter out non-privileged data, and set this attribute before calling jsonSerialize:

```
class FrontEnd implements JsonSerializable {
    private $serialize_all = false;
    private $pub_data   = Array(/* whatever */);
    private $admin_data = Array (/* whatever */);

    public function admin_output ($p) { $this->serialize_all = $p; }

    public function jsonSerialize() 
    {
        return $this->serialize_all 
            ? array_merge ($this->pub_data, $this->admin_data)
            : $this->pub_data;
    }
}

$frontend->admin_output ($user->is_admin ());
$output = json_encode ($frontend);
```

If you have many different objects to serialize, you can subclass them to a class taking care of the problem, like so:

```
abstract class privilegiedSerializable implements jsonSerializable {

    abstract function json_encode ($is_admin); // child picks the export data

    protected function do_encode ($data) // and we take care of the rest
    {
        $this->json_data = $data;
        $out = json_encode ($this);
        $this->json_data = null; // cleanup a bit
        return $out;
    }
    public function jsonSerialize () { return $this->json_data; }
}

class FrontEnd extends privilegiedSerializable {
    private $pub_data   = Array(/* whatever */);
    private $admin_data = Array (/* whatever */);

    public function json_encode ($is_admin)
    {
       return $this->do_encode (
              $is_admin
            ? array_merge ($this->pub_data, $this->admin_data)
            : $this->pub_data);
    }
}

$output = $frontend->json_encode ($user->is_admin())
```

or if the user privilege is a constant during script execution:

```
abstract class privilegiedSerializable implements jsonSerializable {

    static private $serialize_all = false;
    static public function admin_output ($p) { self::$serialize_all = $p; }
    abstract function json_encode (); // child picks the export data

    // same as before
}

class FrontEnd extends privilegiedSerializable {
    // ...

    public function json_encode ()
    {
       return $this->do_encode (
              parent::$serialize_all
            ? array_merge ($this->pub_data, $this->admin_data)
            : $this->pub_data);
    }

privilegiedSerializable::admin_output ($user->is_admin());
$output1 = $frontend1->json_encode ();
$output2 = $frontend2->json_encode ();
```

Comment: Same comment here ^^ : that implies to add a new property (in order to memorize the user, or at least the privileges) to each object. Is this inevitable?

Answer (score 1):

Notify this object before serializng:

```
if ($user->hasPrivileges()) {
   $object->IwillBeSerializngYouForUser($user); 
}
$serialized = $object->jsonSerialize();
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But that implies to add a new property (in order to memorize the user, or at least the privileges) to each object. Is this inevitable?

Comment: Well, you can make decorator function `CustomJsonSerialize()` that takes parameter and adjusts it's properties to serialize and then call  `jsonSerialize` internally if you do'n want to make new property.